# Change all text on page with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, innerhtml, php-5.5

I want to change all text on a page, that got value "Yes".How can I change all "Yes"-value on the page?

I just want that if the value of the text = "Yes", than this must be replaced with `<span class='ic ic-normal ic-icon-yes'></span>`

This is my current code:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additionalgroup = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<section id="additional">
<div class="box-collateral box-additional">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++; ?>
        <h3><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
        <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
             <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
</section>
<?php endif;?>
```

Text inside td-class is loaded dynamically.
Elements does not have any unique ID.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have multiple elements with same id ?

Comment: @KAG Elements do not got any ID anymore, because it is loaded dynamically and an unique ID is not possible

Comment: Do you have in your DOM an element with id="Yes"?? Your code looks for an element styled this way and replace the text inside it.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Sorry, but that is not correct. I change my question for this, because I do not got any unique ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correct understand your problem, you want to change all elements containing a text equal to "Yes" with some pattern. Try this script to achieve that:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text()=='Yes'
}).each(function() {
    this.textContent = "<span class='ic ic-normal ic-icon-yes'></span>"
});
```

Or in pure Javascript:

```
var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var text = allElements[i].innerHTML;
    if (text == 'Yes') {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = "<span class='ic ic-normal ic-icon-yes'></span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the elements do not have any ID. Because it loads dynamically it also does not have any unique class, only even and odd.

Comment: Try this selector: $('*').filter(function() {return $(this).text()=='Yes'}).each(function() {this.textContent = '<span class='ic ic-normal ic-icon-ja'></span>'});

Comment: I updated my answer with a pure javascript solution if you are not using jQuery library. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

To change the text "Yes" in **every innerHTML** of the **tags** in the `<body>` with `<span class='ic ic-normal ic-icon-yes'></span>`:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var children = body[0].children;
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i += 1) {
    var regex = new RegExp("Yes", 'gi');
    var newString = children[i].innerHTML.replace(regex, "<span class='ic ic-normal ic-icon-yes'></span>");
    children[i].innerHTML = newString;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oh54snqv/1/)

Comment: Thanks! But when I tried it inside my table, it does not work. What could be the problem? I added my code above.

Comment: Many thanks! And how do I add an other line to include also if value is No than this span is loaded <span class='ic ic-normal ic-icon-no'></span>?

Comment: And I do got the problem that all value on the page is changed to the span, but I do need to edit only the values inside the tbody of the table. How can I edit this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly you are targeting an element with an ID so there *should* only be one item getting changed. If you were targetting an array of elements chosen by class. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o44pnpdn/)

```
  var yes_divs = document.getElementsByClassName('yes');
    for (var i = 0; i < yes_divs.length; i++) {
        yes_divs[i].innerHTML = 'yes';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the elements do not have any ID. Because it loads dynamically it also does not have any unique class, only even and odd.

Answer (score 0):

If your code loads dynamically based on an action then you can try to perform your script per second like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("Yes").innerHTML = "<span class='ic ic-normal ic-icon-ja'></span>";
}, 1000);
```

Tested: https://jsfiddle.net/dccom5Lv/

Comment: Thanks, but the elements do not have any ID. Because it loads dynamically it also does not have any unique class, only even and odd.

Comment: @Jelle What do you mean _the value of the text = "Yes"_ ? Could you show me the HTML you wanna change?